# SQL how to merge records where start date follows end date

Tags: sql, date

I have a table of data where there may be multiple entries for a single continuous record.

```
Empno           StartDate            EndDate         Wdays
1               2014-07-23           2014-07-23        1
1               2014-11-07           2014-11-29        15
1               2014-11-30           2014-12-07        8
1               2014-12-08           2014-12-19        11
2               2014-11-15           2014-11-16        2
```

Where the start date follows the end date for the same empno I would like only one record to be displayed as follows.

```
Empno           StartDate            EndDate          Wdays
1               2014-07-23           2014-07-23         1
1               2014-07-23           2014-12-19         34       
2               2014-11-15           2014-11-16         2
```

I have solved the date issue with the answer shown below, but can anyone assist me with summing the 'Wdays' for each instance

Comment: this is not a appropriate job for SQL Server, I recommend doing this algorithm in some code that loads its data from the database.

Comment: @AdrianNasui how can you say that querying data is not appropriate for sql server??? That is what is designed to do.

Comment: @Seah I am under the impression that he needed some interval merging algorithm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for those who posted to my original query and my apologies if I wasn't clear on the problem I was having. Here is how  the problem was solved I did this by utilising an answer "ypercube" (https://stackoverflow.com/users/344949/ypercube) posted in 2012

```
With StartData As
( Select
  , empno
  , startdate
  , enddate
  , desc
  , wdays

  From 
   Mytable  

)
,
StartD AS
  ( SELECT 
    Empno
  , startdate
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Empno ORDER BY startdate )
      AS Rn 
FROM
    StartData AS t
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT *
      FROM StartData AS p
      WHERE p.empno = t.empno
        AND p.startdate < t.startdate 
        AND t.startdate <= DATEADD(day, 1, p.EndDate)
    )
 )
, EndD AS
( SELECT 
    empno
  , EndDate
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY empno ORDER BY EndDate )
      AS Rn 
FROM
    StartData AS t
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT *
      FROM StartData AS p
      WHERE p.empno = t.empno
        AND DATEADD(day, -1, p.startdate) <= t.EndDate
        AND t.EndDate < p.EndDate
    )
 )
 SELECT
 s.empno
 , s.startdate
 , e.EndDate
 FROM
StartD AS s
JOIN
EndD AS e
  ON  e.empno = s.empno
  AND e.Rn = s.Rn
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select empno, 
       min(startdate) as startdate,
       max(enddate) as enddate
from your_table
group by empno
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but each empno can have multiple entries which need to exist as multiple entries. Therefore I need to look for the instances where the empno is the same and the startdate of record two follows the enddate of record one. Sorry my sample wasn't clear enough.